# geom_violin - "Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_lines, x$x, x$y, index, x$arrow) : invalid hex digit in 'color' or 'lty'"

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I've tried to find a solution to my problem but I couldn't.

I want to plot geom_violin with `draw_quantiles c(0.25, .50, .75)`, but it returns this error:

> "Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_lines, x$x, x$y, index, x$arrow) : 
>   invalid hex digit in 'color' or 'lty"

The code that triggers the error is the following:

```
p4 <- p3 +  
  geom_violin(data = Data_Set[-c(1:5), ], 
              aes(x = Per_Set, y = Sales, group = Per_Set),
              fill = NA,  colour = "darkgrey", 
              draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 
                           max(Var_Comp1, Var_Comp2, Var_Comp3)))
```

If I run the same code without `draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75))`, it works :

```
p4 <- p3 + 
  geom_violin(data = Data_Set[-c(1:5), ], 
              aes(x = Per_Set, y = Sales, group = Per_Set),
              fill = NA,  colour = "darkgrey")  + 
              coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 
                                       max(Var_Comp1, Var_Comp2, Var_Comp3)))
```

If I run the same code with `draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75))` but without  `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(Var_Comp1, Var_Comp2, Var_Comp3)))` it doesn't work:

```
p4 <- p3 +
  geom_violin(data = Data_Set[-c(1:5), ], 
              aes(x = Per_Set, y = Sales, group = Per_Set), 
              fill = NA, colour = "darkgrey", 
              draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75))
```

Same message error than before:

> "Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_lines, x$x, x$y, index, x$arrow) : 
>   invalid hex digit in 'color' or 'lty"

Could anyone give me a hand with this? I don't know what "color" or "lty" (line type) got to do with this.

ps. p3 has `geom_lines` and `geom_points` and there is no NA in the Data_Set. The y axis is formatted as date in R.

Comment: Please include some data (use `dput()`)to make your problem reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing this error message too ... its a bug that occurs when `geom_violin` can't calculate quantiles for `draw_quantiles = c(...)`.

What I did to work around it is to make sure that each violin had at least 8 data points, which was enough to calculate the 6 quantiles I was looking for `c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95, .99)` without throwing out an `NA` or some kind of error that `grid.Call.graphics` chokes on.

Comment: As with the OP, I can't share my data, so I'm afraid I'll have to leave it to someone else to create a reproducible example.

Comment: Can you not change your column names and add random data to them using `rnorm()` or `runif()` to convert your data to a shareable one?

Comment: Thankfully, it has been replicated and should be solved in ggplot2 3.2.0 ... https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2885#issuecomment-456335156